# Add class to dynamically changing element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use the [attrchange](http://meetselva.github.io/) plugin to listen to a change in one element and add a class to another element. Kind of novice to jquery and javascript and could use some help with this...

```
function navchange() {
    document.getElementByClassName("sticky-element-cloned").addClass('shrinkwrap');
}

$(".sticky-element-original").attrchange({
  trackValues: true, 
  callback: function (event) {
    //event.attributeName - Attribute Name
    //event.oldValue - Prev Value
    //event.newValue - New Value
    navchange();
    }
});
```

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `navchange` function you're mixing your pure Javascript with your jQuery. Try:

`$(".sticky-element-cloned").addClass("shrinkwrap");`

Answer (score 1):

Two things. Firstly, fix your DOM method to make it valid.

```
document.getElementsByClassName(".sticky-element-cloned")[0].classList.add("shrinkwrap");
```

---

Secondly - isn't the class `sticky-element-cloned`? Then why are you using `sticky-element-original` in your jQuery?

```
$(".sticky-element-cloned").attrChange({...});
```

#### Or (do one or the other, not both)

Change it in your JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName(".sticky-element-original")[0].classList.add("shrinkwrap");
```

Comment: Thanks. There are two elements involved — original and cloned.